# Is there a way to get the type of color using a function or api?

Tags: colors

I am trying to make my own website and I needed something to tell me wether the input was a rgb value or a hex value or any other value like cmyk or hsl. And I've been stuck for a day now. Is there an API or function that could help find the type of color used?

function idea:

```js
function determineType(string) {
    //code
}

const rgbValue = '187, 72, 198'
const hexValue = 'ff0000'
const cmykValue = "73%, 45%, 0%, 4%"
determineType(rgbValue) //rgb
determineType(hexValue) //hex
determineType(cmykValue) //cmyk
```

And ofcourse if there is an API out there that could help would be very nice to know.

Comment: Try splitting it by `,` (comma). If there are 3 elements, its RGB, if none, hex, if 4 elements, cmyk. There are probably faster ways but this is what i got

Comment: Never thought about it that way, that helps alot

Comment: Actually, its 1 element if there is no comma in the string, not 0

Comment: Though, even this works it still has some weakness.

Comment: yea it would be very hard to do without weaknesses

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should probably work

```js
function determineType(s){
  let split=s.split(',');
  if(split=='')return;
  let len=split.length;
  return len==3?'RGB':
         len==1?'HEX':
         len==4?'CYMK': null
}

determineType('187, 72, 198'); // "RGB"
determineType('ff0000'); // "HEX"
determineType('73%, 45%, 0%, 4%'); // "CYMK"
determineType(''); // undefined
```